# Google Maps API V3 Custom Control with Google Adsense?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, adsense

I'm pretty new to javascript so please be gentle ;)

I'm using Google Maps API V3 and creating a custom control as per this example.  It's pretty straight forward as it's the example from Google.  What I'm having trouble with though is replacing the .innerHTML with an existing DIV containing javascript.

Ultimately, I'm trying to create a custom control on my Google Map that contains a Google Adsense ad.  Normally I would create a div in my HTML after the body tag and that would contain the javascript code for the Google Adsense Ad.

Normally I would use controlText.innerHTML = 'some html goes here'; for the custom control, but in my case I want to use an existing DIV that contains the javascript code for the Google Adsense ad.

I've tried replacing

```
controlText.innerHTML = 'some html goes here';
```

with

```
controlText.innerHTML = document.getElementById("verticalad");
```

but it just breaks the map.  Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?  I'm hoping it's pretty straight forward to fix.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Custom Controls</title>
    <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>

    var map;
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) {

    controlDiv.style.padding = '4px';

    var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
    controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    controlUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
    controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
    controlUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

    var controlText = document.createElement('div');
    controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
    controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
    controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
    controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';

    //**********************************************************************//
    //Normally this would be controlText.innerHTML = 'some html goes here';
    //**********************************************************************//
    controlText.innerHTML = document.getElementById("verticalad");

    controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(chicago)
    });

    }

    function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: chicago,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {

    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM

    }

    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

    var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);

    homeControlDiv.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER].push(homeControlDiv);
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:700px;"></div>

    //****************************************************************
    // This is the div that needs to be in the custom control
    //****************************************************************
    <div id="verticalad"><script type="text/javascript">adsense code goes here</script></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to move the entire verticalad div in to the control or just the contents of verticalad?
If you want to move it, use `appendChild` instead of `innerHTML`

```
controlText.appendChild(document.getElementById("verticalad"));
```

And if you want the contents, use innerHTML of verticalad

```
controlText.innerHTML = document.getElementById("verticalad").innerHTML;
```

Comment: It would be the content.. Eg.  Inside the verticalad div is some javascript code.. I need to be able to execute that javascript code inside the control.  Incidently, when using either of the above it doesn't work.. it doesn't load the map at all.

Comment: Hmmm.. Ok.. it seems to work ok when I use a div that looks like   <div id="verticalad"><script type="text/javascript">document.write("asdfasdf");</script></div>  .. But when I use a div that looks like this it fails..  <div id="verticalad"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "xxxxxxx";
/* Flighttracker 120x600 */
google_ad_slot = "1674203818";
google_ad_width = 120;
google_ad_height = 600;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div>

Comment: It looks to me like the .innerHTML is interpreting a character it shouldn't be.. I'm just not sure how to fix it.

Comment: At further inspection what appears to be happening is the innerHTML isn't executing the javascript.. it's only printing it.  eg.  If I have the following line.  <div id="first"><script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div>  It will print the contents of show_ads.js instead of execute it.  Anyone know how I can get it to actually execute?

Comment: Try adding a protocol to the show_ads script. Or using this nifty trick: http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: Thanks.. It appears the src begins with the http protocol but it gets stripped or something.. but after further investigation It looks like script blocking is normal for .innerHTML..  I'm not sure I understand the trick in the URL you gave, or how to implement it.  I'll try and study it further.  Can you elaborate on what I would need to do?

Comment: Ok.. I've tried changing the pagead2.google.... to // without the http: in front but it doesn't work.. no ad comes up when I use that.. also, I think changing the code is against their TOS.  I need to find a better way I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a missing semicolon somewhere because I've managed to get this working..

I did indeed keep the Adsense code intact in a div in the Body of the HTML and then used controlText.innerHTML = document.getElementById("verticalad").innerHTML;

I did still have a further problem whereby the adsense ad doesn't show up in IE but I put a meta tag forcing it to emulate IE7 and it's now working fine.. Not the best solution I know but IE7 works fine.  I think the site should look okay in all modern browsers now.

If anyone is interested in seeing the final site, it's at http://www.flighttracker.gleff.com.

Thanks puckhead for your help.

Geoff